# Kubernetes access internal service through external hostname

Tags: kubernetes

I have a K8S with 3 pods:

- A Nginx reverse proxy that route external requests by a external url
- Keycloak, the authentication server
- A rest API backend

I want the rest API can reach the Keycloak through the external url (to get the oidc configuration).

I can make it work with host aliases of the rest api pod, but I need to know the ip of the K8S main ip or the ip of the Nginx service, so I can't make a static configuration.

Is there a way to add another hostname to the nginx service?

Comment: Why don't you put a kubernetes service in front of your pods, so you could reach them internally directly?

Comment: I want to reach them directly but through the public url, is that possible to have multiple service pointing on a same deployment?
In this case, I want the Rest api to call Keycloak throught the reverse proxy by the public url.